# Why I'm getting error when accessing req.user.id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

I have a setup of passport authentication on my express, node project. However when I'm accessing the req.user, I'm getting an error `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)`.
Here is my code

employee.controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';


    export const createEmployee = async (req:Request, res: Response) => {
    const currentUser = req.user.id
    return responseSuccess(res, {newUser:req.body,user: currentUser});
  };
```

passport.ts

```
import passportJWT from "passport-jwt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import env from "../../config/env";
import Employee from "../models/employee.model";
import { PassportStatic } from 'passport';

const { ExtractJwt } = passportJWT;
const JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

export function passportConfiguration(passport:PassportStatic) {
    const opts: passportJWT.StrategyOptions = {
        secretOrKey: env.jwtSecret,
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer'),
    };

  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, async (jwtPayload, cb) => {
      const employee = await Employee.findOne({ _id: jwtPayload.id }).select('-password -otpSecret').exec();
     
      if (employee) {
        cb(null, employee);
      } else {
        cb(new Error("Something wrong in token"), false);
      }
    })
  );
}

export function generateToken(employee:any) {
  return jwt.sign({ id: employee._id, email: employee.email }, env.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: env.jwtExpiresIn,
  });
}
```

Authentication.ts

```
import passport from "passport";
import UnauthorizedError from "../common/http-errors/UnauthorizedError";
import InternalServerError from "../common/http-errors/InternalServerError";
import messages from "../common/messages";

export default async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("jwt", {}, (error, user, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(new InternalServerError());
    }

    if (user) {
      req.user = user
      return next();
    }
    return next(new UnauthorizedError(messages.auth.invalidToken));
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

What I tried is

- When I tried to remove the `Request` on `req:Request` the error is gone. But it's standard to put the Type in the req param.
- List item `const currentUser = req.user?.id` still error persist

I'm not sure if this is tsconfig issue. Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": ["src/index.ts", "config/env.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
      /* Basic Options */
     
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
      "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
      "lib": ["es2015", "es2017"] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
      "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
      "checkJs": true /* Report errors in .js files. */,
      "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
      "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
      "typeRoots": ["src/typings", "./node_modules/@types"],
      "strictBindCallApply": true /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */,
      "noImplicitThis": true /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */,
      "alwaysStrict": true /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */,
      "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    
  },
  "include": ["server/typings/*.ts", "server/typings/customer.d.ts"]
}
```

Sorry for adding the image. Just to show that the id is underlined error.
[image]

I'm stuck figuring out why.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the type definition of `Request` from `express` module, which has no `user` attribute but [only those found here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req). You have to write your own type definition or tell TS that it is there in some other way.

Comment: sorry I'm new with the backend development.  Is there a way I can bind the `user` on the `req:Request`?

Comment: You could extend the type ``Request`` with an interface ```interface UserRequest extends Request { user: { id: string } }```. But honestly why using the ``Request`` type if it is clearly something custom to your code logic? Or let's better highlight why are you setting something on the ``request`` object instead of passing the user object separately?

Comment: Because I'm using the standard data that are pass from router to my controller which is the `req: Request, res: Response`. My router is  `router.post("/create",authentication, validate(EmployeeRequest.createEmployee), wrap(createEmployee));` and the controller will be `export const createEmployee = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {}`.

Comment: yeah I got it from your code. It's a bit messy tbh. You are "capturing" and "misusing" an object from another library and putting stuff into it directly and then using the type definitions made for them. Of course you are getting type errors because you didn't tell TS anywhere about what you are doing and so it assumes you are trying to get data that it thinks is not there.

Comment: Sorry if my code is bit messy. I'm just new with development. So you mean, My fault is on the `passport.ts` where I'm injecting the `user` data? How should I inject the user data in `request`?

Comment: It is not a fault. You *could* do it like this if it suits you, but *should* you in terms of good programming? You can ask that yourself. Anyways your problem is foremost with the type system now so jsut declare that you have user objects on the request type. Add that information to tell TS that it is there and the error goes away :) e.g. ``interface UserRequest extends Request { user: { id: string } }`` and use that new type/interface ``UserRequest`` in your code ``req: UserRequest``

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own custom interface `extends` Express Request type to have your own type check

```
import { Request } from "express";

export interface AuthenticationRequest extends Request {
    User?: // define your type
}

export const createEmployee = async (req:AuthenticationRequest, res: Response) => {
    const currentUser = req.user.id
    return responseSuccess(res, {newUser:req.body,user: currentUser});
};
```